# Changing Wordpress footer text to black so it is invisible

Tags: css, wordpress

Im trying to get rid of a tacky "powered by Wordpress" footer from my bottom of my website.

I figured out how to remove it below. But when I do, all the text on my website gets deleted.

```css
.has-text-align-center {         
  display: none;            
}
```

so I want to find a way to change the text color to black so it doesn't appear.

I know #000000 codes for black.

I tried

```css
.has-text-align-center{
  display:color: #000000;
}
```

but the same problem. How do I isolate the removal of that footer rather than deleting the entire text of the website.

Comment: I'm not offering legal advice, but I'm fairly certain removing and hiding would be considered the same. If such as rule existed, it would usually state something along the lines of "_XYZ_ must be clearly visible on the site".

Comment: In CSS, it is `attribute: value` always, so just a single `:`. In your case, `color: #000000;`. Or, `font-size: 0;`

Comment: That all said, `has-text-align-center` is a very generic class, and I wouldn't be surprised if it is used elsewhere. You might want to look for something more specific that targets just your specific case.

Comment: `display:color: #000000;` is wrong/invalid, needs to be `color: #000000;`. But actually, you need to find a more specific selector for your CSS rule so that it doesn't affect other elements too. Might be found with the help of the browser tools, depending on which browser you use.

Answer (score 0):

Go to the text you want to hide, right click -> Inspect Element and try to create a more specific query because the class has-text-align-center is very generic.

For example in the screenshot bellow lets say we want to hide the Twitter element.

[image: example element]

Start from the element you want which is type "anchor" so "a" and go to the parent element which is an h2 element with some classes, add `h2.bottom-notice` then go again to the parent element which is a div with an id, so add the id "#answers"

The final result is the above items in reverse so:
the first query[space]second query[space], we are separating by a space because we then go to it's child

```
#answers h2.bottom-notice a:nth-of-type(3)
```

Edit: I didn't even check the screenshot, there was a small mistake but the point is the same, so we add :nth-of-type(3) to actually pick up the twitter (third element) and not the first element.

and as you can see on the second screenshot we picked up the element.

[image: query result fixed]

Now this was an easy example but you can create a query for anything you want, and if you still can't do it post either your URL here or a screenshot of the text you want to remove in the inspect element window.

Edit: Also, in case you want to actually hide the element and not change the color you can apply the property: `display:none!important;` instead of the one with the color.